# Inter solution dependencies, how do you handle it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget

My software consists of dozen of solutions where each has multiple projects inside it. The projects inside these solutions have dependencies on each other(across solutions because the projects which has dependencies on each other which are in the same solution uses project dependencies). How do you share those dependencies ? I also have external dependencies for instance NUNit and other things and those i handle with NuGet. I thought whether NuGet would be a good thing for internal dependencies but it is not since i would have to edit the packages.config every day so all modules are running with the correct versions of my internal dependencies. How do you handle this ? I don't want to commit the binaries to SCM.

donnibg

Comment: I'm facing similar problems here, although in a smaller scale, in Visual Studio 2017. Has anything improved in the two years that have passed since this question was asked?

Answer (score 1):

We have been struggling with this for quite some time now as well. Especially when your projects change all the time.

Our solution for those projects was to include them in all solutions needed. Depending on their dependent assemblies, you will end up with a lot projects in your solution. The downside of that is that the build time can increase very drastic (depending on your projects) but you will always have the latest sources.

The projects which are quite stable have been added to our Nuget server, thus available for all solutions. The configuration of Nuget (especially then versioning of assemblies) can be very cumbersome ;-)

Comment: Yes that sums the solution that i was thinking of but it would be nice to hear others if they have found other ways to tackle this problem.